# Barplot grouped by row index

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

## Background

I'm reading *Introduction to Machine Learning with Python* and tried visualization of In[45] in [Chapter 2](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/blob/master/02-supervised-learning.ipynb). First, I fitted 3 `LogisticRegression` classifiers to Winsconsin cancer dataset using different `C` parameters. Then, for each classifier, I plotted coefficient magnitudes of each feature.

```
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cancer = load_breast_cancer()

for C, marker in [(0.01, 'o'), (1., '^'), (100., 'v')]:
    logreg = LogisticRegression(C=C).fit(cancer.data, cancer.target)
    plt.plot(logreg.coef_[0], marker, label=f"C={C}")
plt.xticks(range(cancer.data.shape[1]), cancer.feature_names, rotation=90)
plt.hlines(0, 0, cancer.data.shape[1])
plt.legend()
```

[image: Plot by markers]

I prefer barplot than using markers in this case. I'd like to get a graph such as:

[image: Barplot]

I achieved this by the following workflow.

### Step 1: Create a `DataFrame` holding coefficient magnitudes as a row

```
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pandas as pd

cancer = load_breast_cancer()

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cancer.feature_names)
for C in [0.01, 1., 100.]:
    logreg = LogisticRegression(C=C).fit(cancer.data, cancer.target)
    df.loc[f"C={C}"] = logreg.coef_[0]

df
```

[image: DataFrame of features]

### Step 2: Convert the `DataFrame` into a `seaborn.barplot`-applicable form

```
import itertools

df_bar = pd.DataFrame(columns=['C', 'Feature', 'Coefficient magnitude'])
for C, feature in itertools.product(df.index, df.columns):
    magnitude = df.at[C, feature]
    df_bar = df_bar.append({'C': C, 'Feature': feature, 'Coefficient magnitude': magnitude},
                           ignore_index=True)

df_bar.head()
```

[image: DataFrame for Barplot]

### Step 3: Plot by `seaborn.barplot`

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.barplot(x='Feature', y='Coefficient magnitude', hue='C', data=df_bar)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

This yielded the graph I wanted.

## Problem

I think Step 2 is tedious. Can I make the barplot from `df` in Step 1 directly or make `df_bar` by one-liner? Or is there a more elegant workflow to get the barplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas plots grouped barplots column-wise. Hence it should be possible to do

```
df = df.transpose()
df.plot(kind="bar")
```

without using seaborn.

If the use of seaborn is for whatever reason required, step2 from the question could probably be simplified via `pandas.melt`.

```
df_bar = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=["index"])
sns.barplot(x="variable", y="value", hue="index", data=df_bar)
```